# Gradually aggregating a string column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I would like to gradually aggregate a string column in Oracle sql.

From this table:

```
col_1 | col_2
-------------
1     | A
1     | B
1     | C
2     | C
2     | D
```

to:

```
col_1 | col_2
-------------
1     | A
1     | A,B
1     | A,B,C
2     | C
2     | C,D
```

I tried `LISTAGG` but it won't return all rows due to `group by`. I have about 2 million rows in the table.

Comment: The problem, as stated, is not deterministic. How do you know, from the inputs, that the output should show 'A' then 'A,B' and then 'A,B,C'?  What makes the row with the value 'A' the **first** row for `col_1 = 1`? Or do you in fact have an additional column that defines the order of your rows?

Comment: Also, is there a maximum length of the **output** strings that you can guarantee in advance? If not, you will need to work with `CLOB` in the output - which, for example, rules out using `LISTAGG()` (despite the "correct answer" you already selected).

Comment: Btw, `listagg()` doesn't work for `oracle10g` which's one of the tags. e.g. the solution without `listagg()` is more generic.

Comment: @mathguy It is a good point. There is an index col which defines the order. I can find the max length of the output strings in advance.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It was a mistake. I was looking for 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support accumulating string concatenation with a single `listagg()` expression.  However, you can use a subquery.

Just one note:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to have an ordering in mind.  The following code adds an ordering column:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, 1 as x, 'A' as y from dual union all
      select 2, 1 as x, 'B' as y from dual union all
      select 3, 1 as x, 'C' as y from dual union all
      select 4, 2 as x, 'C' as y from dual union all
      select 5, 2 as x, 'D' as y from dual
     )
select t.*,
       (select listagg(t2.y, ',') within group (order by t2.id)
        from t t2
        where t2.x = t.x and t2.id <= t.id
       ) 
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. I do need the ordering. I am not sure how I can do for 2 million rows. Even though the example table is only five rows, I have an actual table with 2 million rows.

Comment: @user11871120 . . . You can just run the query.  The number of rows in the table doesn't matter.

Comment: The number of rows in the table obviously **does** matter (certainly the number of rows with the same value in `col_1`), since `listagg()` only works with `VARCHAR2`, not with `CLOB`. Throw too many values at `listagg()` and it will error out.

Answer (score 3):

A hierarchical query option looks like this:

```
SQL> with t as (
  2        select 1 as id, 1 as x, 'A' as y from dual union all
  3        select 2,       1 as x, 'B' as y from dual union all
  4        select 3,       1 as x, 'C' as y from dual union all
  5        select 4,       2 as x, 'C' as y from dual union all
  6        select 5,       2 as x, 'D' as y from dual
  7       )
  8  select x,
  9         ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(y, ','), ',') result
 10  from (select x,
 11               y,
 12              row_number() over (partition by x order by y) rn
 13        from t
 14       )
 15  start with rn = 1
 16  connect by prior rn = rn - 1 and prior x = x;

         X RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 A
         1 A,B
         1 A,B,C
         2 C
         2 C,D

SQL>
```